# How to implement O(1) dividend algorithm in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

Language: solidity
Platform: Ethereum, EVM
Question: There is currently a dividend pool. 2% of the transaction fee will be distributed at 0 UTC every day, and 2% of each transaction must be distributed in real time. How to achieve that each user can get their actual average score, but will not cause Gas to exceed?

Comment: Synthetix liquidity mining and Sushiswap liquidity mining reward contracts (MasterChef) are good examples how to do real-time dividends. However, as a disclaimer advanced Solidity skills are needed to tackle the problem: https://docs.sushi.com/products/masterchef-v2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.